# Apache Velocity: Escape character not working for PHP as associative array key

Tags: java, php, templates, velocity

I'm using Velocity (1.7) to generate PHP code.

I set up Velocity with strict excape, that helps a little:

```
p.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_REFERENCES_STRICT_ESCAPE, "true");
```

But I'm running into a problem with the following line in the template:

```
\$result['${attribute.Name}'] = \$this->${attribute.Name};
```

The Output is:

```
$result['${attribute.Name}'] = $this->color;
```

But it should be:

```
$result['color'] = $this->color;
```

Edit:

I found a way to solve the problem:

```
#set($d = "$")
${d}result['${attribute.Name}'] = \$this->${attribute.Name};
```

But I don't like the solution to introduce an additional variable only to solve a possible bug in Velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Velocity 1.7, `\` is no longer an escape character. When rendering `\$result['${attribute.Name}']`, `\` is printed verbatim, since it's not a Velocity syntax character, `$result['${attribute.Name}']` is recognized as an array access on the object referenced by the `$result` variable, but since there is no array behind that variable, the whole output is printed verbatim. This is how Velocity works: whatever is recognized as valid Velocity syntax, but can't be evaluated or results in a `null`, is printed back into the output.

Since you're mixing two similar syntaxes, Velocity and PHP, you need a way to delimit one from the other. Escapes are the right way to go, but `\$` isn't one. You have to use a variable to get the `$` sign.

The recommended way is to use the [`$escapetool.d`](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html#getD%28%29) escape tool, but that requires configuring tools and is longer than just a `${d}`.

Or you can use the [unparsed content](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/vtl-reference-guide.html#Unparsed_Content) escape syntax:

```
#[[$result[']]#${attribute.Name}#[['] = $this->]]#$attribute.Name
```

Comment: Oh, I noticed that I read an outdated version of the velocity user-guide without the detailed information of the fact that escaping can fail. There they recommend using `#set( $D = '$' )`, see [escapingvalidvtlreferences](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences). In this documentation `\\` is already mentioned as a valid excape character.
The **unparsed content** hint may be useful in other situations, tanks.